# Tenant at Sufferance

Tags: residential-lease

A Florida residential tenant contract is written such that after the term the renter is on a month to month contract and either party may terminate with 15 days notice.

Is this example coined by "Tenant at Sufferance"?  If not what are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The difference is the tenancy at sufferance is a status that arises from a wrongdoing by the tenant. It is a tenancy at sufferance when a tenant *wrongfully* stays in possession of the property after the expiration of the tenancy.

Comment: Once the landlord accepts rent under the tenancy at will, the tenant at sufferance becomes a tenant at will (i.e., month-to-month) until one party or the other gives the required 15-day notice of termination.

Comment: The landlord would not "accept rent under the tenancy at will" in that case because there is no tenancy at will in the situation described by OP. If the tenant is holding over without the approval of the landlord, it is a tenancy at sufferance. The landlord has a choice at that point: to accept tenant (then it can become a tenancy at will, assuming they don't agree to another lease in writing) or it may turn into eviction proceedings.

Comment: The situation described by OP is a month-to-month contract, also known as a "tenancy at will".  I think you meant to say "there is no tenancy at sufference" in that situation.  I'm saying that if there _were_ a tenancy at sufference, the acceptance of rent may create a tenancy at will.

Comment: Noted - you're right. I got sidetracked with the 'sufferance' part. The above situation is tenancy at will, but would have been 'at sufferance' in a similar situation without the contract provision. My apologies for the confusion!